# Web API in asp.net web forms application redierct to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

In my asp.net web forms application i have added a folder at root level "WebAPI" it have a web api controller and it is authenticate by token. asp.net web format application have the form authentication. When i call api from rest client it redirect to login page.

API Response:-

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Login/Default.aspx?      ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2fcustomer%2fGetSmsCount">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Root level web.config:-

```
 <location path="WebAPI"> <system.web> <authorization> <allow users="?"/>
 </authorization> </system.web> </location> <system.web><authorization> 
 <deny users="?" /></authorization> </system.web>
```

---

I have given the access to anonymous on webapi folder but still it is redirecting to login page.

Comment: What error is showing in the browser console for that request

Comment: browser return following response:-  <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Login/Default.aspx?      ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2fcustomer%2fGetSmsCount">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

Comment: I think you need to add permissions for path like "api/Customer" or just "api", not for "WebAPI"

Answer (score 0):

Check whether u given the Correct path of API

Comment: Path is correct, if comment out "<deny users="?" />" api can make success call.